# Why are real time systems concurrent?

Tags: java, multithreading, time, concurrency, real-time

Is it because  timing constraints imposed on real-time systems means that a thread or task should control its own execution based on timings where a sequentially executed program may not be able to guarantee timings are achieved due to its task load?

Regards, thanks.

Comment: Actually there are lots of real time systems (and then I assume we're talking about hard rt guarantees?) that run on small embedded devices where even the concept of several threads doesn't really exist. So your assumption is wrong to begin with :)

Comment: When a system controls time sensitive external processes and reacts to unpredictable external inputs it cannot always wait to complete a task before responding or tending to another task. It must at times handle two or more tasks concurrently.

Comment: Agreeing with @Voo, I used to work on rt code that used no processes, no threads, relied on interrupts and coop multitasking. I consider that code concurrent. What do we mean by concurrent today?

Comment: This is where i am slightly lost i have read in my lectures that real-time systems are inherently concurrent as the model the real world. This phrase confuses me

Comment: @MikeHoward It's what I was trying to say in my first comment. The real world does not wait. If the teapot boils while you are reading the paper, you may briefly interrupt your reading while you pour the water, but you continue where you left off. That's coop multitasking. If you are a real multitasker, you might keep reading while pouring!! That's a bit like a multi-core cpu running two threads concurrently.

Comment: The realtime systems that are concurrent (not all are), are so because it's a pain to write complex software without there being the concept of running concurrent threads/processes/tasks

Comment: 'Concurrent' to me means multiple cores.  'real time' means response contraints and deadlines.  Nearly all embedded controllers have only one core and I would not consider them concurrent, no matter how many interrupts and threads they have. Real-time requirement for high-performance IO and the availablility of controllers with enough RAM for more than one stack, are pushing out cooperative schedulers and polling, but even so, I would not call a preemptive scheduler with 10 hardware interrupts and 16 threads 'concurrent' if running on one core.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a real time system with one thread so it doesn't have to be concurrent.

Using threads can help in real time systems, but they can introduce their own problems.

Perhaps you associate real time with concurrency because you have to be more aware of what every thread is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Peter's answer, but I'd like to elaborate.

The exogenous physical devices that are part of a real-time system -- i.e., the part that the real-time software and computer interact with -- may have any amount of concurrency from none to whatever. Real-time systems are NOT inherently concurrent, but many if not most of them are to some extent.

Regardless of the amount of concurrency the exogenous part has, the real-time software can in general have any amount of concurrency from none (the so-called "master thread" Peter alluded to) to as many schedulable threads/tasks/etc. as is deemed appropriate.

And as Peter noted, the more concurrency in the software, the more complex and difficult concurrency control gets. This is true in general, and exacerbated in real-time software due to the time constraints. It is claimed by some reputable software scientists that the human mind is not well suited to managing high degrees of asynchronous concurrency of anything.

Edward Lee is one of the most outspoken critics of concurrent threads, as articulately documented in this tech report "The Trouble With Threads" [www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf).

Comment: I read "The Trouble With Threads" some years ago.  As I read through the report, I was not too impressed by the taking apart of naive thread implementations with gross overreliance on locking, even though actors, message-passing, erlang etc. were at least mentioned.  When I got to the conclusion, however, I was just.. well, words fail me. 'Deterministic ends should be accomplished
with deterministic means'.  Our desktop systems are chaos built one interrupt at at time.  I/O interrupts arrive in near-chaotic order making threads ready. The trouble with threads is that there is no alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Concurrent<>Real time, as others have posted.

Real time systems tend to use premptive schedulers because of the good IO performance. Cooperative or non-existent scheduling are only suitable for applications where latency and overall IO performance is not important - ruling them out for many/most 'real time' tasks.

Whether 'real' concurrency is acutally used, ie. mutiple cores, is another matter.